# Prime Numbers and Combinatoric Division

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, divisibility

True or false, for all primes p > 2, there are an infinite number of positive integers n for 
which p does not divide ${2n \choose n}$.

I think the answer would be no, but I am not sure. Since n! has all numbers less than n as factors I would assume that p would be among those. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Your reasoning is not complete anyways... remember that $\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)(n!)}$.  Even if $p$ is a factor of $n!$, it will also be a factor of the other $n!$ as well as a factor of $(2n)!$, but you have to ask the question of *how many times* $p$ is a factor of each to find out whether the resulting number is still divisible by $p$ or not.  Some of the $p$'s will cancel from numerator and denominator, but how many is not immediately obvious.  You then have to argue for or against the existence of infinitely many $n$ for which $p$ does not divide $\binom{2n}{n}$.

Comment: Note for example $\binom{10}{5}=252$ is not divisible by $5$ but is divisible by $7$.  $\binom{20}{10}=184756$ again is not divisible by $5$ and is also not divisible by $7$.  On the other hand $\binom{16}{8}=12870$ is divisible by $5$ but is not divisible by $7$.  Other oddities occur, but the question is if for a given $p$ whether or not there are *infinitely many* values of $n$ such that $\binom{2n}{n}$ is not divisible by $p$.

Comment: How would I find if there are infinite or finite values? From what I understand from your post, only if the exponent of p in the prime factorization of 2n is greater than two times that of n then p divides the binomial coefficient.

Comment: Not quite... only if the exponent of $p$ in the prime factorization of $(2n)!$  (*don't forget the factorial*) is higher than two times that of $n!$ will it be... as for an answer... fractal already gave a start to a satisfactory answer below, and I don't expect there to be a cleaner solution than using legendre's formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is actually yes.  For a hint, see [Legendre's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula).

Solution:

For $p$ to not divide $\binom{2n}{n}$, $v_p((2n)!)$ must be exactly $v_p(n!) + v_p(n!) = 2v_p(n!)$ (where $v_a(b)$ is defined as the largest nonnegative integer $k$ such that $a^k$ divides b).

So the question is equivalent to, given a prime $p > 2$, do there exist an infinite number of $n$ such that $v_p((2n)!) = 2v_p(n!)$?  I claim the answer is yes.  Consider $n = p^i$ for some positive integer $i$.  Then by Legendre's Formula, $$v_p(n!) = \Bigg\lfloor\dfrac{n}{p}\Bigg\rfloor + \Bigg\lfloor\dfrac{n}{p^2}\Bigg\rfloor + \cdots + \Bigg\lfloor\dfrac{n}{p^i}\Bigg\rfloor = p^{i-1}+p^{i-2}+\cdots+1,$$$$v_p(2n) = \Bigg\lfloor\dfrac{2n}{p}\Bigg\rfloor + \Bigg\lfloor\dfrac{2n}{p^2}\Bigg\rfloor + \cdots + \Bigg\lfloor\dfrac{2n}{p^i}\Bigg\rfloor \\ = 2p^{i-1}+2p^{i-2}+\cdots+2 = 2v_p(n!),$$ as desired.  Since there are infinitely many powers of $p$, the conclusion follows.

The key idea here is that there are no powers of $p$ between $p^i$ and $2p^i$.  This only works when $p > 2$, and fails for $p = 2$.  In fact, $2$ divides $\binom{2n}{n}$ for *every* positive integer $n$, which you can use $v_2$ and Legendre's formula to prove.

Comment: what exactly is $v_p$?

Comment: $v_p(m)$ basically counts the exponent of $p$ in the prime factorization of $m$.  For instance, $v_2(24) = 3$, $v_3(81) = 4$, and $v_5(1001) = 0$.  It is very useful notation!

Comment: Can you really pull the 2 out of the floor function? Wouldn't that change the values? For example ⌊2*1.5⌋=3 while 2⌊1.5⌋=2

Comment: @shrindle notice that he started with "**Consider $n=p^i$ for some positive integer $i$**."  Ordinarily your complaint would be valid, but since $\frac{n}{p^k}=p^i/p^k=p^{i-k}$ is an integer for all values of $k\leq i$ it follows that $\lfloor \frac{2n}{p^k}\rfloor = \frac{2n}{p^k}$ since it is an integer, and for convenience, we rewrite again with floor signs $\dots = 2\lfloor \frac{n}{p^k}\rfloor$.  Now... consider the case where $k>i$... each term would be less than one, thus the floor is zero and so is often omitted from the expression (*note his expression ended at $p^i$*)

Comment: Nice elaboration @JMoravitz, thanks.  Another thing I should have noted in the solution is why it only works for $p > 2$; I will edit that in.